Isekai manhwa with a pink-haired female lead who has divine power and is married to a comatose duke
I'm trying to find this full colour manhwa.
It is an isekai/transmigration manga where the female lead (FL) wakes up in a novel, in the body of a pink-haired lady married to a noble (probably a duke) on the order of the Duke's stepmother. The Duke is in a coma and the FL is originally killed for poisoning her husband to death in the novel. The FL possess divine power and unknowingly heals the Duke and also threatens the doctor who provides the poison. She also gains the trust of the high priest/pope who is at odds with the stepmother. The stepmother poisons the Duke to make her own son the Duke.

I Thought You Were A Time Limited Husband.
From Anime-Planet:

"The deadline is six months, within which you must kill your husband." On the first night of their marriage, I possessed the body of 'Alice,' a villainous supporting character who was ordered by her mother-in-law to kill her husband. I thought I was married off to a duke who's a living corpse for the sake of money, but lo and behold, this duke has a great body and is handsome as well. Instead of killing him, I looked for a way to survive by using divine power instead of poison. "Mother, I will become a priestess for the duke! As a priestess, I shall pray for the duke's well-being for the rest of my life!" On the day I was about to leave the duke's mansion, my husband who had been unconscious suddenly woke up. "You're the one who brought me out of the darkness, so take responsibility." He wakes up and demands I take responsibility after saving him.


Hi, welcome to the site. We'd be grateful if you'd edit this to tell us a bit more about this manhwa and how it matches the OP's description of the manhwa they were looking for.
